# Cual es la gracia de pasarte de la Interface de Reporte a la de Cierre si no tienes votos de Cierre Vigentes?

Tags: soporte, reportes, votos-de-cierre

Estaba revisando este post: [No puedo cargar datos cuando subo archivos a godaddy, en local si cargan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/498082/no-puedo-cargar-datos-cuando-subo-archivos-a-godaddy-en-local-si-cargan)

y concuerdo en que a ese post le hacen falta Detalles; como se que no me quedan Votos de Cierre para el día de hoy me dispongo a hacer un reporte y que otros sean los que hagan el voto de cierre:

al entrar a la interface de reporte veo que me quedan 56 votos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al dar click en **Necesita Mejoras** me envía a la interface de cierre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***¿Por lo cual me envía a un cajón sin salida y sin poder hacer nada, es esto correcto?***

en este caso el sistema debería dejarme seguir haciendo reportes ... esperar 3 horas para tener votos de cierre no ayuda a la comunidad ...
o son 56 o son 20 ... pero dejen hacer algo ... XD

Comment: Esta pregunta es interesante, pero está fuera del alcance de lo que podemos hacer dentro del sitio en sí. Deberías plantearla en [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: me extraña que nadie se haya quejado de esto...

Comment: Creo recordar que, cuando subes de rango, al reportar una publicación para cerrar, realmente estás emitiendo un voto, porque ahora tienes más poder que antes. Entonces, queda claro que los reportes son para niveles de reputación inferiores al tuyo y debes adaptarte a lo que realmente te corresponde.

Comment: @Triby ento ces para que me sale que tengo 56 votos de reporte... cual es el punto de mostrar algo que nonpuedes usar...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, eso es difícil saberlo, lo ideal sería que la plataforma te muestre solo las opciones que realmente puedes usar.